# Howto send a zip file with the right name from a Google Cloud Function using Python?

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have code that generates a zip file and offers it as a download. It is handled in a Google Cloud Function. Generating and downloading the zipfile is no problem but I can't get the function to return a zip file with the given name. The download always defaults to the function name 'fdsuitebuilder'.

This is the code;

```
from dsuite import DSuite
from flask import send_file

def main(request):
    ... #creating and filling a DSuite object called ds
    ffullname = ds.write("tmp", "output.stix")   
    return send_file(ffullname, mimetype='application/zip', attachment_filename='output.stix', as_attachment=True)
```

So what I expect as I trigger the function is to generate a download called output.stix (which is actually a zip file) but instead I get a download called 'fdsuitebuilder'

I guess this has to do with GCP not being flask but if someone knows the right way to generate the correct download name I would be happy to know!

Regards

Comment: I do not know the function `send_file` that you are using. However, the solution is to implement the HTTP headers for `Content-Disposition`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```py
from tempfile import mktemp
from flask import send_file


def test(request):
    fn = mktemp()
    with open(fn, "w") as f:
        f.write("Hello")
    return send_file(
        fn,
        mimetype="application/zip",
        attachment_filename="output.stix",
        as_attachment=True,
    )
```

```
$ curl -I https://us-central1-gcf-sendfile-test.cloudfunctions.net/test
HTTP/2 200
cache-control: public, max-age=43200
content-disposition: attachment; filename=output.stix
content-type: application/zip
etag: "1573510438.2602577-5-834405785"
expires: Tue, 12 Nov 2019 10:13:58 GMT
function-execution-id: 7sb3tp6j260y
last-modified: Mon, 11 Nov 2019 22:13:58 GMT
content-length: 5
date: Mon, 11 Nov 2019 22:13:58 GMT
server: Google Frontend
```

I don't see a reason why your example wouldn't work. Can you confirm that it's successfully deployed the version you included?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, somehow the cloud repo wasn't synced with the cloud function.